# Read live html file in NSData

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on my app where I have to read an HTML file:

The URL is `http://www.youtube.com/user/danielmorcombefd/videos`.

Then I want to save it as a HTML file, say `example.html`, and then store it's data in an `NSData`:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"example.html"];
```

Kindly suggest me solutions.

Answer (score 3):

`-initWithContentsOfURL:` perhaps?